# Call a generic function with matching generic arguments

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to write a function that takes as arguments another function and it's args, then executes the function with the provided args and return the result while preserving the types.

As long as the provided function has a static return type, it's fine. But when that function's return type depends on the params, I'm not able preserve the return type.

Here is my failed attempt. I hope it will clarify what I'm trying to achieve:

```
function f<A>(args: A) {
  return args
}
// Calling the fuction directely works as expected:
const result = f('test') // OK: type of result is 'test'

// I tried this to be more explicit about the return type but it does not work
type ReturnTypeWithArgs<
  F extends (args: any) => any,
  A extends Parameters<F>[0],
> = F extends (args: A) => infer R ? R : never

// This is the function I'm trying to build
function callFunction<F extends (args: any) => any, A extends Parameters<F>[0]>(
  f: F,
  args: A,
): ReturnTypeWithArgs<F, A> {
  return f(args)
}

// I'd like to get the same returned type when using callFunction. But it doesn't work:
const result2 = callFunction(f, 'test') // KO: typeof test2 is unknown
```

Comment: This is not possible in TypeScript yet... wait hold on I'm finding the issue...

Comment: You can't substitute generics in function types; there's a suggestion at [ms/TS#40179](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40179), but it's not part of the language yet. If you refactor you can take advantage of [higher order type inference from generic functions](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) like [this playground link](//tsplay.dev/NarY0m) shows. Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing? (Please mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Comment: Thanks @jcalz ! It does answer my question pretty elegantly. I think you can definitely write an answer. Unfortunately, I'm still not able to fully solve my issue but this is another topic 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no purely type-level way to take a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function type like `<T>(t: A<T>) => R<T>` and an argument type like `X` and get the compiler to tell you what the return type would be if you called the function with an argument of type `X`.  You can't use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) like [the `ReturnType<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) or [the `Parameters<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) utility types; it ends up just replacing the generic type parameters with their (possibly implicit) constraints, so `<T>(t: A<T>) => R<T>` becomes just `(t: A<unknown>) => R<unknown>)`.

There's an open suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#40179](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40179) for type operators that answer the above question.  It's marked as "Awaiting More Feedback", without much engagement.  If you want to see it happen you might go there, give it a , and describe your use case and why it's needed... but it probably wouldn't have much effect one way or the other.  For now it's not part of the language.

---

Currently TypeScript's support for higher order generic manipulation all involves some value-level code that makes it into emitted JavaScript.  If you *call* a generic function, it will perform the type manipulation you want, but you can't do it without a function somewhere.

Luckily you *can* write your `callFunction()` function, though, by refactoring to use separate generic type parameters for the arguments and return types.  That is, don't start with `F` of some function type and try to tease apart its argument type `A` and return type `R`.  Start with `A` and `R` directly.  This will allow the compiler to perform its [higher order type inference from generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#30215](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215):

```
function callFunction<A, R>(f: (arg: A) => R, args: A): R {
    return f(args)
}
const result = callFunction(f, 'test') // string
```

That's what you wanted to see.  You don't get `unknown`, but the actual `string` type of the input.

---

Well, there's the small discrepancy of `A` and `R` being inferred as `string` instead of the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"test"`.  If that matters you need to give the compiler a hint to infer narrower types there.  There's an issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#30680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680) asking for some easy way to do this, but for now I use the workaround of defining a `Narrowable` hint type as a constraint.  It could look like:

```
type Narrowable = string | number | boolean | null | undefined | bigint | {};
function callFunction<A extends Narrowable, R>(
    f: (arg: A) => R,
    args: A,
): R {
    return f(args)
}
const result2 = callFunction(f, 'test') // "test"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAPAQQHwAoCGAnAcwGcAuRNASkQG8AoRBxPAUyhDyX2NoF9aIERKE2ZEQAG2EBeZFgDkUUVDlUA9KsQB5ANJkoATwAOzRHGAixkxDCKIFSubVoHjiAHL48cAO44ARuImMkJ4MGAEiAA+iGAgALZ+zHhRiH5wcIE4SNGx4uIp4AAmzMBhzIUpfjAEYcLR1DwA3LSgkLAIiBA4eQBi4NDwYOiIzAAeimCFth54Xr4BzAA0iABK2PSMwGS4hGSUiFIYq4sbDFyk5CcUZCs0pyJsHLLnFLz8gsIsllAATAed3XEfTagywwGW9iEKkQ6kQACJFEI4U4gA)

Comment: This is an impressive detailed answer, thanks @jcalz ! Though in my actual use case, I wish `callFunction` could actually take an object with functions rather than just a function. Unfortunately, when I try to do that, I'm losing the type specificity. In case you want to help and have an idea, here is a playground: https://tsplay.dev/WY3BzN

Comment: The higher order function inference as implemented in [ms/TS#30215](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215) only works in very specific circumstances.  Looks like you want [ms/TS#49505](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49505) which isn't implemented